# How to make two ''where' conditions on SQL select query

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

column 1| column2 | column 3|

01                      45                     heavy 
02                        50                       easy
04                      100                      middle

I want a result that will show all records that if  in '**column 3**' is '*heavy*' then '**column 2**' must have value greater then 50, and if in '**column 3**' is not '*heavy*'  then '**column 2**' must have value greater then 90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` / `when`:

```
select ...
where column2 > (
    case column3
        when 'heavy' then 50
        else 90
    end
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can translate your logic *directly* into a `where` clause:

```
where (column3 = 'heavy' and column2 > 50) or
      (column3 <> 'heavy' and column2 > 90)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon Linoff. That is what I wanted ,,Thnx for saving my time ,, bye